# Need help tracing crash

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, shared-libraries, ndk-stack

I am trying to fix a `fatal crash 11` error that occurs within my application. I was able to use `logcat` and `ndk-stack` to trace it to `art_quick_instrumentation_entry at crtbegin_so.c:?` within `/apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so`. But from there I am not sure how to go about trying to fix this. Attempting to open the file in a text editor or in Android Studio gives me a bunch of non-readable gibberish.

Any ideas on how I can go about trying to fix this?

Comment: You should proabbly focus on the lines in the stacktrace that refer to code in your application.

Comment: There wasn't any. Which is why I traced the logcat and ndk-stack. But I was able to figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Turns out it was related to a dialog popup within a menu. Moved the dialog to fire outside of OnOptionsSelect and it works fine.